# Is it safe to add ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT = armv6 armv7 in XCode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, arm, three20

I have an iOS project that requires compatibility with iOS 3.X devices. Thus, I must target both armv6 and armv7 architectures.

I have added an xcconfig file to my project and to my dependent projects (I use three20 and it comes with a common xcconfig file).

In both my project's xcconfig file and the shared three20 xcconfig file, I have added this line:

```
ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT = armv6 armv7
```

Based on my understanding and what I have observed, that resets the value of that build parameter to what it was back in XCode 3.X.

Are there any bad consequences to doing this that I should be aware of? Or is this an acceptable way to build both armv6 and armv7 in XCode 4.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst i can think about is new default compiler clang 3.0 having some nasty bugs with armv6 architecture. If you want to stay on the safe side you could also change the compiler used to the one you used before updating xcode (llvm-gcc-4.2 or gcc-4.2).

Comment: I have encountered numerous UI bugs when building my code in XCode 4.2 (UI elements shifted on screen, background colors not working). I did not realize this option to compile with the older compiler existed, but I will definitely look into it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any fix for this issue ? . did compiling with old ones helped ?